# cgi.FieldStorage() broken

Tags: python, cgi

I'm running a very simple python webapp with python2.7, and cgi.FieldStorage() always returns FieldStorage(None, None, []) even when I put arguments in. The source code of my test is

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import cgi
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print
    print cgi.FieldStorage()
```

and even when I submit the url as url.py?arg=test&arg2=test

in my web browser FieldStorage(None, None, []) is returned. What's going on?

Comment: Your are instantiating a new FieldStorage and not loading your params.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: the code is right, if the program is actually run with the CGI interface. `FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('arg', 'test'), MiniFieldStorage('arg2', 'test')])` here. However, are you sure the python code is run as a CGI? What is the server you are using? You could try renaming the file to `url.cgi` to make sure that it is really CGI.

Comment: Renamed to .cgi, still got the same output. Apache.